# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() When Hosting

Tags: codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have error like this when hosting :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sqlsrv_connect() in
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php:77
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php(90):
>   CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver->db_connect() #1
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\database\DB_driver.php(116):
>   CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver->db_pconnect() #2
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\database\DB.php(149):
>   CI_DB_driver->initialize() #3
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\core\Loader.php(347):
>   DB() #4
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\core\Loader.php(1172):
>   CI_Loader->database() #5
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\core\Loader.php(153):
>   CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #6
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\core\Controller.php(52):
>   CI_Loader->initialize in
>   D:\HostingSpaces\kirapacc\kirapac.com\wwwroot\pesanclaris\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php
>   on line 77

but in my localhost running, without any error.

Comment: PHP Driver for SQL Server is not installed correctly.

Comment: in this hosting i have 1 directory (inside is CI with sqlsrv) can connect, then i create one directory again (inside is CI with sqlsrv) but show error like that